# onprogress response text error

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Having a weird issue with onprogress for my XMLHttprequest.

I'm using the following code to log the response onprogress:

```
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
      target = (event.currentTarget) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
      console.log('response: ',target.response);
}, false);
```

If i console.log just `target`, I get an object, where I can see that response has text like so:

[image]

But if I try and log `target.response` or `target.responseText`, it is completely empty. No errors or even a length on the string.

Pretty sure it has something to do with the response being JSON, but I'm not sure where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `progress` is only triggered *during* the XMLHTTPRequest, not at the end when the response was received? There are known problems when logging objects in Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196. MDN says about `readyState 3`: *"Downloading; responseText holds partial data."*.

Comment: You should get multiple progress events with growing response strings (and it can be empty at the first time). If you log the whole request object, you will only see the response that has already fully arrived.

Comment: I have two responses and I've put a 10 second sleep inbetween them. So this isn't the issue.